# Do we need to consider the line-ending recently(2018) In Eclipse or STS?

Tags: eclipse

In `Prferences`->`General`->`Workspace`->`New text file line delimiter`, we could set it to `Unix` or `Windows`.
I tried these **two options** on Windows7 and they both worked well.
It means that Eclipse can deal with unix-like files and windows-like files on Windows7.
So I'm wondering **whether it's important to set line-ending** in Eclipse or STS.

In another word, when developing java applications with Eclispe on Windows 7, which option should I use? `Unix` or `Windows`?

[image]

Comment: It surely is important if you care what type of line delimiter eclipse uses? I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: In another word, when developing java applications with Eclispe on Windows 7, which option should I use? `Unix` or `Windows`?

Comment: There is no right or wrong option; it depends on your specific situation. But it can be relevant when using Git. See [Eclipse & Git: Mind your Windows line endings!](http://mike.meessen.biz/blog/?p=368)